# JSF - Updating Model Values in Controller Bean

Tags: jsf

I have a Controller bean (SearchController) that has two managed bean as managed properties (SearchCriteria, SearchResults; both of which are session scoped).

When the user hits the find button, the action method that is executed is in SearchController.

The SearchCreteria managed bean has a method called search().  This method returns a new SearchResults object.  In the controller bean, I am setting the searchResults managed property to be this new SearchResults object.  The searchResults object contains what I expect during that request, but the object does not persist in the managed bean.

I understand that I am changing what object that searchResults is referencing, but what I don't understand is why JSF isn't updating the model to use the new object.  Any ideas what I'm missing or don't understand?  I am using JSF 1.1 on WebSphere 6.1.

If I put the search method in the SearchResults managed bean, it works.

The line in SearchController.find() that is commented out is the one that presently works.

```
public class SearchController {

SearchCriteria searchCriteria;
SearchResults searchResults;
ResultsBacking resultsBacking;


public String find()
{

    setSearchResults(searchCriteria.search());
//      searchResults.findSearchResults(searchCriteria);

    if (!searchResults.resultsFound())
    {
        return "noresults";
    }

    return "success";
}


public class SearchCriteria {

public SearchResults search()
{
    SearchDAO sdao = new SearchDAO();
    ArrayList<Group> list = (ArrayList<Group>)sdao.findGroups(this); 

    SearchResults searchResults = new SearchResults();
    searchResults.setSearchResults(list);
    return searchResults;
}

}


public class SearchResults {

List<Group> searchResults;

public void findSearchResults(SearchCriteria criteria)
{
    SearchDAO sdao = new SearchDAO();   
    this.setSearchResults(sdao.findGroups(criteria));
}   
}
```

Comment: It's really hard to help without seeing the code in question...

Comment: I agree that it's hard to visualize the problem without some snippets. Check my answer, I've posted an example snippet. See if that's true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a nut, you've something like this:

```
@ManagedBean
public class SearchController {

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{searchCriteria}")
    private SearchCriteria searchCriteria;

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{searchResults}")
    private SearchResults searchResults;

    public void find() {
        searchResults = searchCriteria.search();
    }

}
```

And the `#{searchResults}` in the view doesn't contain the desired results?

This sounds like as if you're accessing the search results by `#{searchResults.someData}` instead of `#{searchController.searchResults.someData}` and you're expecting that overriding the `SearchResults` property inside the `SearchController` will replace the current session scoped managed bean.

This is wrong.

You need to solve it by either using `#{searchController.searchResults.someData}` instead

```
<h:outputText value="#{searchController.searchResults.someData}" />
```

Or by overriding (setting) the *properties* of `SearchResults` instead of overriding the whole managed property of `SearchController`:

```
    public void find() {
        searchResults.setSomeData(searchCriteria.search().getSomeData());
    }
```

Or by manually replacing the bean in session (not recommended).

```
    public void find() {
        searchResults = searchCriteria.search();
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
            .getSessionMap().put("searchResults", searchResults);
    }
```

Comment: thanks BalusC, I've set the properties of SearchResults and that did the trick.

Of the 3 you've listed, which one do you generally use in these situations?

Comment: Depends on the context and requirements. It's either first or second, but normally not the third. If `SearchResults` really needs to be an **independent** managed bean, then I'd go for second. But if it **cannot** survive without `SearchController` in any view, then I'd go for first and stop the `SearchResults` being a managed bean.